# Как красиво и правильно реализовать открытие и появление верстки на Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

у меня есть вот такой компонент, сделанный на Vue.js:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
При нажатии на наименования банка у меня должен раскрываться список программ, который он предлагает.
Реализовано это вот так:

```
<div
  v-for="(bankOffers, bankName) in offers.data"
  :key="bankName"
  class="mt-[25px] sm:m-[42px] cursor-pointer">
  <div @click="seen = !seen" class="flex flex-row items-center">
    <div class="w-[52px] h-[52px] pt-[20px] shadow-brand rounded-brand"></div>
    <div class="ml-[20px] text-[18px] font-medium">{{ bankName }}</div>
    <svg
      v-if="seen"
      class="svg-icon w-[12px] h-[12px] ml-[25px] text-brand-gray mr-auto flex-shrink-0"
    ><use xlink:href="#chevron" width="100%" height="100%"></use></svg>
    <svg
      v-else
      class="svg-icon w-[12px] h-[12px] ml-[25px] text-brand-gray mr-auto flex-shrink-0 -rotate-90">
      <use xlink:href="#chevron" width="100%" height="100%"></use>
    </svg>
  </div>
</div>
```

А в Data:

```
data() {
    return {
      seen: false,
    }
  },
```

По такой логике, при открытии одного банка, открываются сразу все предложенные банки, я хочу, что бы открывался только один банк, подскажите пожалуйста как можно это реализовать, чем красивее, тем лучше :)

Answer (score 0):

Воспользоваться объектом `seen: {}`.

```
@click="seen[bankName] = !seen[bankName]"
v-if="seen[bankName]"
```